# scraping items with x-ray that don't have a single root

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, x-ray

I'm running into trouble with scraping items that don't have a single root. Something that is necessary I believe with [x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray)

Consider scraping hacker news where each headline is made up of two TRs:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="athing>content item 1</tr>
  <tr>content item 1</tr>
  <tr class="spacer></tr>
  <tr class="athing>content item 2</tr>
  <tr>content item 2</tr>
  <tr class="spacer></tr>
</tbody>
```

As can be seen, there's no common root-node per item.

Does x-ray support scraping in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

you could use + to select sibling

```
x(html, 'tbody ',
    ['tr.athing, tr.athing+tr:not(.athing):not(.spacer)']
)
(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

result:

```
[ 'content item 1a',
  'content item 1b',
  'content item 2a',
  'content item 2b' ]
```